# Verilog: Module that accepts two 4-bit inputs and outputs a 4-bit output

Tags: verilog

1. Accepts two four-bit inputs named i_a and i_b.
2. Outputs a four-bit number named o_sum.
3. Outputs a one-bit number named o_err if the sum is greater than 1111.
4. Uses an always@ block to continuously add the two inputs and assign the resulting sum and error bit to the outputs.

New to verilog, can someone tell me if I am doing this right?

```
module add4 (
  o_sum, // Sum out
  o_err, // Error out 
  i_a, // Addend A 
  i_b, // Addend B 
);

  output reg [3:0] o_sum; 
  output reg [1:0] o_err;
  input [3:0] i_a, i_b;

  always@( * ) 
  begin
  if ( o_sum = i_a + i_b >1111 ) 
    o_sum = o_err;  
  else
    o_sum = i_a + i_b;
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: your 'o_err' is a 2-bit signal, not one bit as in the description, `1111` is a decimal number, you probably meant a binary one.  Do not put assignments in the condition of 'if'.  There is no point to assign o_err to o_sum.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of mistakes in your code

1. `output reg [1:0] o_err;` You said o_err is 1 bit, it should be output reg o_err;
2. `o_sum = o_err;` Your o_sum will not be 4 bits then
3. `if ( o_sum = i_a + i_b >1111 )` This cannot evaluate if o_sum is greater than 1111 as o_sum is 4 bits. Also, it should be 4'b1111 else it is a decimal number.

Now coming to the code, this should work,

```
module add4 (
  o_sum, // Sum out
  o_err, // Error out 
  i_a, // Addend A 
  i_b, // Addend B 
);

  output reg [3:0] o_sum; 
  output wire o_err;
  input [3:0] i_a, i_b;

  reg carry;

  always@( * ) 
     {carry, o_sum} = i_a + i_b;

  assign o_err = (carry == 1)?1'b1:1'b0;

endmodule
```

Also, please try to use testbench to test correctness of your design. That would be better appreciated by the members.

Comment: I see the `<test> ? 1 : 0` anti-pattern enough that I swear someone must be teaching it.  The ternary is entirely redundant.  Just leave the test as is and it'll work equivalently.  In this case I'd go a step further and just have o_err directly in the carry position of the add.

Comment: You are right. That could have been done. I did this to make this appear simpler